# Unable to Connect Moodle with nextcloud Error: Can Not Download File

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, moodle, nextcloud

I am trying to get files from Nextcloud to moodle courses with File activity.
After selecting files and save, it throws error says can not download file.

I have used OAuth 2 to connect Nextcloud from moodle here is screen shot

[image]

I don't know why Login is not connected. I followed instruction as per guidelines.
https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/OAuth_2_services

Here is my error logs:

```
Error code: cannotdownload
* line 380 of /repository/nextcloud/lib.php: repository_exception thrown
* line 1283 of /lib/filelib.php: call to repository_nextcloud->reference_file_selected()
* line 547 of /mod/resource/locallib.php: call to file_save_draft_area_files()
* line 107 of /mod/resource/lib.php: call to resource_set_mainfile()
* line 128 of /course/modlib.php: call to resource_add_instance()
* line 168 of /course/modedit.php: call to add_moduleinfo()" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: moodle.domain.com, request: "POST /course/modedit.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "moodle.domain.com", referrer: "https://moodle.domain.com/course/modedit.php?add=resource&type=&course=7&section=0&return=0&sr=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a troubleshooting tip here to try to connect again

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/OAuth_2_Nextcloud_service#Troubleshooting

> When I try to create an access controlled link I get a "Cannot download this file" error.
> This may happen if the system account is not connected. Go to Site administration > Server > OAuth 2 services and try to connect again the Nextcloud system account.